# Unreal Engine Mobile Rotation Using Touch

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Hope Everyone is doing ok, I have a problem can someone tell me why my rotation starts snapping if I increase the sensitivity to like 50 but it is smooth at like 10

Code in the picture Below..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmzAs.png

Comment: You're multiplying an int by 20 and a float (delta time) with a certain minimum value of around 0.01. It should come as no surprise that the result won't go below a certain amount, which makes it appear to "snap". You might want to consider reducing your sensitivity and squaring the distance of the difference vector you compute

Comment: something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/E5NZjnz.png) maybe with a smaller sensitivity. This way, the bigger the touch movement, the more like high sensitivity it behaves. his means you can have the senstitivity small so that degrees aren't skipped when rotating slowly, but the faster the touch moves, the ever more rotation happens in each pixel of touch movement.

Comment: but won't that make the rotation inconsistant which is bad for a FPS game right!

Comment: It would be consistent, but it would just be consistently non linear. Nothing wrong with that.